# Discovering the database name in Firebird UDF

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

I was wondering if there is a way to find out what the database name is from Firebird UDF.

I know I can get it using `RDB$GETCONTEXT` and pass to an UDF as a parameter, but in my case it's desirable to avoid changing the signature of the UDF.

So maybe there is a way to access the context from UDF or some other way of getting db name?

Update: judging by the content of Firebird_2_5\include, what I wanted is impossible.

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible within the UDF.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I can, but not from UDF, unfortunately.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name UDF are simply a way to call functions declared in external libraries. Those external functions don't have context information about Firebird. Maybe with the new Firebird 3 functionality of external modules this might become available.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Writing functions in PSQL is something that is also added in Firebird 3 ;)